# C# Inheritance with generic interfaces and fluent methods

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, fluent

I'm trying to figure out how to build a generic structure of interfaces to use with fluent notation.

I'm trying with a structure as the following:

```
public interface IGeneric<out T>
    where T : IGeneric<T>
{
    T Foo1();
    T Foo2();
    T Foo3();
}

public interface ISpecific_1 : IGeneric<ISpecific_1>
{ }

public interface ISpecific_2 : IGeneric<ISpecific_2>
{
    ISpecific_2 Bar1();
    ISpecific_2 Bar2();
    ISpecific_2 Bar3();
}

public abstract class GenericImpl<T> : IGeneric<T>
    where T : IGeneric<T>
{
    public T Foo1()
    {
        //Do things
        return (T)(object)this;
    }

    public T Foo2()
    {
        //Do things
        return (T)(object)this;
    }

    public T Foo3()
    {
        //Do things
        return (T)(object)this;
    }
}

public class SpecificImpl1 : GenericImpl<ISpecific_1>, ISpecific_1
{

}

public class SpecificImpl2 : GenericImpl<ISpecific_2>, ISpecific_2
{
    public ISpecific_2 Bar1()
    {
        //Do things
        return this;
    }

    public ISpecific_2 Bar2()
    {
        //Do things
        return this;
    }

    public ISpecific_2 Bar3()
    {
        //Do things
        return this;
    }
}
```

The IGeneric only accepts its own implementations as T, to make sure that Foo1(), Foo2() and Foo3() will return the correct type for fluent notation.

The GenericImpl is abstract (not mandatory, but I would like to make them use the specific classes instead) and implements IGeneric.

ISpecific_1 implements IGeneric with its own type (this mean that Foos methods in the Generic class will return ISpecific_1).

Specific_1 implements ISpecific_1 and extends GenericImpl<ISpecific_1> as well.

The same for ISpecific_2 and Specific_2, except for some Bars extra methods.

This seems to work because I can do this:

```
ISpecific_1 spec1 = new Specific_1();
spec1.Foo1().Foo2().Foo3(); //Everyone returns ISpecific_1 that extends the Generic class with the Foos

ISpecific_2 spec2 = new Specific_2();
spec2.Bar1().Foo1().Bar2().Foo2().Bar3().Foo3(); //Everyone returns ISpecific_2 with the Bars. Also the Generic Foos methods are available.
```

while I can't do this:

```
ISpecific_1 spec1 = new Specific_1();
spec1.Bar1().Bar2().Bar3(); //ISpecific_1 nor IGeneric don't declare Bars methods
```

And now the question(s):

First one:
In the Foos methods I have to manually cast the return value by using

```
return (T)(object)this;
```

I can also make T : class and use

```
return this as T;
```

Are them safe or am I missing a case where that cast fails?

Second one:
Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _"The IGeneric only accepts its own implementations as T"_ - I don't believe this is possible and probably causes a circular dependency!

Comment: This is known as the  curiously recurring template pattern and you could do something like `public class MyThing : GenericImpl<ISpecific_2>` so now `T` is not going to be `MyThing` but that works because `ISpecific_2` is a  `IGeneric<ISpecific_2>` so be aware that it does not guarantee the generic type is exactly the implementing class type.

Comment: @phuzi I thought so in the beginning, I also was surprised when i discovered that I was wrong.

Comment: @juharr good point, didn't thought about that. Thank you!

Comment: Code in the question is safe in the sense of it will consistently fail (as GenericImpl  never is T) - please clarify the question if it is the kind of safety you are asking about

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't find any really clean solution: I had to sacrifice a bit of the structure.

I made almost all the properties public (this was not a problem in my case); this allowed me to manage all the methods as generic extension methods instead of class methods and still they can operate on the public properties.